# 200 kgs bench press, squats and deadlift challenge

Tags: strength

I have taken up a challenge to do 200 kg bench press, 200 kg deadlift and 200 kg squat within 8 months. I weigh 83 kg and can do 1 rep with 100 kg for the above 3 exercises. I take 150gms grams of proteins on a daily basis through different types like whey , eggs , sprouts , milk, chicken.  What are my chances of accomplishing it? Please let me know. How can I improve my chances of doing it?? Note I was able to reach my current level in 4 months time  . Would wearing a safety belt be beneficial to lift heavier weight?

Comment: There's no way for anyone on this site to tell you if you'll be successful. Any answer would be a guess.

Comment: @JJosaur sir would you like to comment/ answer this  I would really appreciate your valuable advice.

Comment: Your goal is to lift 2 times your current max potential in 8 months. I'd be honest, it's not an easy task, but we don't know how your body responds to lifting, so it's hard to tell. All you can do is do progressive overloading. That means add 5-10 pounds to the weight a week progressively. You have around 34 weeks. Does that mean you'll be able to lift 170-340 lbs more? Overloading is not linear from what I know. It works in waves. There's no way to answer, other than trying. Having said that, stay safe, your safety is more important that any competition. Take it easy.

Comment: @xCodeZone sir / madam, I have made some edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your question has been edited, and you are asking about tips to improve your personal best. You have also mentioned that you reached your current personal best of 100 kg, in 4 months after you started lifting. That's quite impressive. I'd like to share a few basics. When you start lifting, smashing personal records by progressive overloading is easier. Then you arrive at a point, where it feels like the saturation is achieved. 200 Kg is roughly around 450 lbs. That's a big goal to achieve in the time you have mentioned.

Your goal is to lift 2 times your current max potential/personal best in 8 months. Progressive overloading is the answer. That means add 5-10 pounds to the weight a week progressively. You have around 34 weeks. Does that mean you'll be able to lift 170-340 lbs more than your current personal best? To answer that I'd say, overloading is not linear. It works in waves. Also, after reaching a certain point, adding anything extra would take longer than what it used to be, when you begun.

So some days you may end up smashing your own record, and the other day you may struggle to lift even 80% of it. Why? Human body works that way. Several factors including diet, rest, stress and fatigue level, condition of your muscles, injury etc are linked to your performance.

Now, to get stronger, which is your goal, you need to give yourself plenty of rest and go for the right kind of nutrition along with lifting. Your protein intake is good, but to make it great, consume somewhere around 160-180 grams everyday. That means, 0.9- 1 gram per body weight in lbs. That's pretty essential for muscle repair. You have mentioned that you are 83 kg which makes you 180 lbs, so that's how the math works. Along with that, eat enough calories to fuel your muscles and right amount of micro nutrients for complete nutrition.

There are many risks involved. When you go that heavy, first thing to take care is safety. You said you want to wear a belt. Go for it while doing dead-lifts and squats, but that's not sufficient. Always and always have an experienced spotter to spot you, and a qualified trainer to check your form. Form is most important, and if you are just doing it to get it done, you'll face injuries. So try doing it right first. Use power racks while doing bench press and squats. You wouldn't like to hurt yourself and be out of training, or start again from ground zero.

Move on gradually. Keep adding weights every week, and never rush no matter how tempting it is. If it's a challenge from a friend or another competitor, losing it is better than being hurt and not being able to move. If it's for a competition, you can always compete next year, if you fail to do it this time.  Wish you the best.